# How to make iframe content fit and scrollable?

Tags: html, css

I have an `iframe` element that I want to make its content readable which means I basically can see the page of the iframe properly and make it scrollable so that we can see the whole page without reducing its zoom or size. I can't make it like I want. I can't make it scrollable and can't see the whole content of the iframe.

```css
#janela, #docwindow{
    position: absolute;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    left:200px;
    top:200px;
    border-radius:10px black solid;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  
/****JANELA****/
#janelaCalendario{
  position: absolute;
  width:800px;
  height:700px;
  left:500px;
  top:200px;
  border-radius:10px black solid;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#calendar{
  width:100%;
  height:90%;
  border:none;
}

#janelaCalendarioHeader{
  z-index:10;
  height: 30px;
  background: rgb(30,87,153); /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%,rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e5799', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

#closeCal{
  width: 20px;
  height:20px;
  top:5px;
  right:5px;
  background-color: none; 
  position:absolute;
 border-radius:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="janelaCalendario" >
    <div id="janelaCalendarioHeader">
            <header class="windowTop">
            <img  id="closeCal" class="X" src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/oxygen-icons.org/oxygen/256/Actions-dialog-close-icon.png" alt="X" onclick="fecharCal()">
            </header>
    </div>
    <iframe src="https://teamup.com/ksbe6drnzpwdbyrgp2" id="calendar" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple use a wrapper div and keep the iframe inside it.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <iframe src="https://teamup.com/ksbe6drnzpwdbyrgp2" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: But i don't want to make it that big I just to be able to scroll in the iframe so that the whole page can be visible. for example u open the open u see the left side of it and u scroll right in the bottom bar of the iframe and u see the other side

Comment: Adjust the width and height of wrapper according to your needs

Comment: Approve the answer if it helped